# YASM equivalent for NASM built-in __BITS__ macro?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, yasm

I have a piece of nasm assembly code which I want to be yasm compatible, but running the assembler on it gives errors on a couple of nasm-specific macros and includes, mostly related to the conditional

```
%if __BITS__ == 32
```

Where `__BITS__` is the current bit mode.

Does YASM have equivalent functionality, or any other way to follow a code path depending on the bit mode?

Comment: You could always define __BITS__ yourself on the command line when compiling code. example: `yasm -D__BITS__=32 file.asm`, `yasm -D__BITS__=16 file.asm` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to define a macro to use instead of `bits`, like this (untested):

```
%macro myBits 1
    bits %1
    %assign __BITS__ %1
%endmacro
```

Of course in this case you'd have to replace every occurance of `bits 16`, `bits 32` and `bits 64` in your source code with the equivalent `myBits` macro.

Note that I'm not quite sure how `bits` is implemented in YASM. It might be that it is a macro itself (that internally relies on a lower level directive like `[bits]`). In this case you may be able to redefine the `bits` macro and avoid the need to change anything.

For source code that doesn't use the `bits` directive at all, I'd just define `__BITS__` with the assembler's command line argument.